# "unsigned char*" в managed byte array

Tags: visual-c++, bytearray

в `ImageCopy.data` лежат данные картинки.

```
IntPtr ptr(imageCopy.data);
int ss = strlen((char*)imageCopy.data);
Byte bytes[] = new Byte[ss];
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, ss);
```

Выдает ошибки

- Error (active)   E0520   initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object
- Error    C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned char []
- Error    C2665   'System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy': none of the 16 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: @nick_n_a хочу перевести в array byte

Comment: @nick_n_a `unsigned char*`

Comment: @nick_n_a, попробовал не помогло те же ошибки

Comment: Ага... в плюсах всё веселее.. вот решение есть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403005/copy-unmanaged-data-into-managed-array

Comment: Я не вижу смысла в написаном коде, потому что strlen применять к картинке нельзя. Но для того что б показать работу Marshal::Copy - покажу. А ваше ss - прийдётся найти как вычислить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно поправить код... много поправок 1.IntPtr нужно кастить `void*`  2. Marshal::Copy - не ест обычные массивы, оно хочет array CLI-шный т.е. `cli::array`. Т.е. где-то так

```
int dataSize= strlen((char*)imageCopy.data)+1; /*Если ASCII-Z то +1 обязательно*/
array<byte>^ _Data=gcnew array<byte>(dataSize);
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(
   IntPtr( ( void * ) imageCopy.data), 
  _Data, 
  0, 
  dataSize );
```

Источник https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403005/copy-unmanaged-data-into-managed-array

P.S. `strlen` - делать картинке.... нельзя. Потому что это до первого нуля... что в результате будет..... обрезаные байты.  Такой метод можно применять к строкам, и то нужно писать `int dataSize= strlen((char*)imageCopy.data)+1;` потому что нужно учесть ноль в конце ASCII-z. dataSize для картинок определяется другими способами, и это можно обсудить в отдельном вопросе. Тут чисто как сделать `Marshal::Copy`. Для работы с **строками** хочу обратить внимание на метод `Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi` и `Marshal::PtrToStringBSTR`, что б не вышло много лишних преобразований.

Если не компилируется - подключить `#include "stdafx.h"` либу

Comment: array от System или std?

Comment: ошибка syntax error: '<'

Comment: `cli::array` нужен